# SQL match on letter and number arrangement

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to write an SQL statement which finds all rows which match a specific arrangement of letters/numbers?

i.e. `SELECT myCol FROM myTable WHERE myCol='<letter><letter><number>'`

Should return 12X and 34Y but not 123X or 34YY

I am using MySQL.

Comment: As a follow-on to this question, let's try without using REGEX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064711/sql-match-on-letter-and-number-arrangement-without-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't got MySQL on this machine to test but I think

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myCol REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9][A-Z]$'
```

Should do it. `^` is an anchor for start of string, `$` for end of string and the rest should be self explanatory.

Looks like you could also use `REGEXP '^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]$'` but completely untested and just going off the docs.

Comment: It is MySQL. How would regexp work? I've never done it before.

Comment: you would need to use something like `WHERE  myCol  REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9][A-Z]$'`

Comment: When you say "something like", I think you mean "exactly this". It's just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: If it's longer, it seems you can use `WHERE myCol REGEXP '^[0-9]{x}[A-Z]{y}$'` where x is number of consecutive numbers, and y is number of consecutive letters.

Answer (score 1):

For sql server, you can use with [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx). For mysql, you have [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

EDIT : Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out I was wrong and that PATINDEX does not support regular expressions. That's correct but after some googling I found that you can [use regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) in sql server because it hosts CLR.

Comment: Describing the patterns you can pass to `PATINDEX` as regular expressions seems a little over-generous. Even it's own documentation only claims that you can pass wildcards.

Comment: @Damien Correct. I edited the post. I didn't check on it because I was certain it supported regex. Shows again how wrong you can be.

Answer (score 1):

Many database management systems support regular expressions. So, in PostgreSQL 9.x for example, you can do this . . .

```
create table mytable (
  mycol varchar(10) primary key
);

insert into mytable values 
('12X'),
('34Y'),
('123X'),
('34YY');
```

And then

```
select * 
from mytable
where mycol ~ ('^[0-9][0-9][A-Z]$');
```

Answer (score 1):

And Oracle's version.. here it is:

```
SELECT myCol
  FROM myTable
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(myCol, '^\d{2}[A-Z]$')
```