# SQL match on letter and number arrangement without using regular expressions

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2003

Is it possible to write an SQL statement for MySQL which finds all rows which match a specific arrangement of letters/numbers without using REGEXP?

i.e. SELECT myCol FROM myTable WHERE myCol='*{number}{number}{letter}*'

Should return 12X and 34Y but not 123X or 34YY

[I have asked a similar question before- (
[SQL match on letter and number arrangement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042340/sql-match-on-letter-and-number-arrangement)). The difference is that I have discovered that I cannot use regular expressions with the ADO.Net driver I am using. Whatsmore, I cannot update it since I am using Visual Studio 2003 which is not compatible with later versions.]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more. Why should it not match `34YY`?

Comment: Well, it seems like you should either change the pattern in your example or choose different values for the right answers. The pattern says *{letter}{letter}{number}*, while your correct values are rather *{number}{number}{letter}*. (I believe, by *{number}* you meant *{digit}*.) Other than that, I think your idea is clear basically.

Comment: @Sachin 34YY has an extra unwanted letter at the end, so it shouldn't match.

Comment: @Andriy Sorry, typo. (I seem to be good at them). It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM myTable 
WHERE SUBSTRING(myCol, 1 , 1) >= 'A' 
AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 1 , 1) <= 'Z' 
AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 2 , 1) >= 'A' 
AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 2 , 1) <= 'Z' 
AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 3 , 1) >= '0' 
AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 3 , 1) <= '9'
```

Comment: BETWEEN would fit perfectly into your solution, I think.

Comment: This looks great. Think it should be <='9' at the end, not >='9'.

Comment: This is what I've ended up using. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, but it would be very slow and resource-intensive ...

```
SELECT 
    myCol 
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    CHAR_LENGTH(myCol) = 3 
    AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0') 
    AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 2, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0') 
    AND SUBSTRING(myCol, 3, 1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

That'll match "12X" and "34Y" but not "123X" or "34YY".

Comment: "slow and resource-intensive" are my middle names ;-)

Comment: This works. I know it's a real messy compromise but it's just the situation I've ended up in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to state the accepted answer explicitly:

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM myTable 
WHERE SUBSTRING(myCol, 1 , 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' AND
SUBSTRING(myCol, 2 , 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' AND
SUBSTRING(myCol, 3 , 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
```

(mixture of Ken's answer and Andriy's suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  ( myCol LIKE '12X%' OR myCol LIKE '34Y%' ) 
AND    myCol NOT LIKE '34YY%'
```

Rough example, but should help you figure the problem out. Can't help more since your example isn't that precise.

Comment: And to help further, % is a wildcard, can appear in front and in the end of string, and I think also in between, but have not tested it myself and don't have a MySQL connection handy to try it right now. So '%ABC%' would be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is as simple as your example (ie. no parameters) then can you use a Stored Procedure to return the results using Reg Exp? In that case the driver shouldn't know or care that you're using Reg Exp.

Comment: My actual query is a bit more complicated. But I think a stored procedure would work still. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT myCol FROM myTable WHERE myCol REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{1}'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: For your reference: the question text `without using REGEXP`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EMS SQL Manager for MySQL, you can use RegEx to filter data.

```
SELECT col 
FROM tbl
WHERE col REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{1}$'
```

RegEx:

```
^[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{1}$
```

`^` = starts with

`[[:alpha:]]` = alphabet

`[[:digit:]]` = numbers

`{n}` = exactly n instances of

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this method is incompatible with my ADO.Net driver. It doesn't error for the above example, but it would return 0 rows every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the first two digits using LIKE, and for the third use an ascii range.  The first two digits can use an ascii range too, but LIKE should be better.

```
select *
from tbl
where length(n) = 3
  and '0123456789' like concat('%',mid(numcol,1,1),'%')
  and '0123456789' like concat('%',mid(numcol,2,1),'%')
  and ASCII(upper(MID(numcol,3,1))) between 65 and 90
```